# DTO in nest js accepting more parameter as compared to DTO

Tags: nestjs

I have a DTO

```
export class UpdateUserRoleDTO {
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  readonly userId:number;

  @ApiProperty()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsNumber()
  readonly roleId: number;
}
```

My controller looks like this

```
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe())
  @Post('/update')
  async updateUser(@Body() updateUserDto: UpdateUserDTO): Promise<User> {
    return await this.userService.updateUser(updateUserDto);
  }
```

Whenever client sends a request with the following payload

```
payloadObj = {
   userId : 1,
   roleId : 1,
   xyz : 'assddcds',
   someotherkey : 'fsdvs'
}
```

It's hitting my service file .I want to avoid this make sure only parameter mentioned in DTO should be passed else it should give 400

Comment: @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({forbidNonWhitelisted: true, whitelist: true}) add this decorator to your controller

Comment: Just two sidenotes: There's no need to await the service instead of just returning the promise and you typically don't need a route called "/update" in your API, because you already have the http request method "post" to differentiate between actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

given your code I'd pass the [whitelist](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#whitelisting) option set to ***true*** to the `ValidationPipe` you're instantiating, like so in your controller:

### controller.ts

```js
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ whitelist: true }))
@Post('/update')
async updateUser(@Body() updateUserDto: UpdateUserDTO): Promise<User> {
  return await this.userService.updateUser(updateUserDto);
}
```

This should do the work.

Let me know if it helps, otherwise don't hesitate to comment & share your findings ;)